# Delegating authentication in Windows AD domain

Tags: windows, active-directory, ldap, authentication, radius

In a Windows AD domain, when the client (user) authenticates against the Domain Controller, is it possible to delegate the authentication to another LDAP/RADIUS server?

We have a ton of services in our network and we need to authenticate against a single user/password database. For some reason, we don't want to use AD for this.

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably manage to create an LDAP referral that works for this, but it highly depends on the version/vendor for those LDAP sources.

I would not count on that for Radius authentication sources. This question needs more context

Comment: this is not an answer, or a comment, I myself is looking for other experts to comment on this: sounds like an identity management software is called for to link between different directories?